# Keep getting not enough space for object heap in java

Tags: java, android, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I am trying to run the vFileServe of project anarchy, but i always have this error even though i set a parameter on my java

Here is my error

```
Loading deploy parameters from Source\Vision\Samples\Engine\FileServe\FileServe_
android_arm_vs2010_anarchy.vcxproj_Dev.deploy
Creating apkFile ../../../../../Bin/android_arm_vs2010_anarchy/Dev/libFileServe.
apk for library ../../../../../Bin/android_arm_vs2010_anarchy/Dev/libFileServe.s
o
Android platform (SDK) android-10
Removing dir AndroidTemp\armeabi-v7a
Making a raw (so uncompressed) dir for the gdb server, native .so etc...
Done
Generating classes.dex file
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Command finished with error code '1'
```

Here is my java parameter

[image]

I tried putting `-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx512m` also but doesnt work either

Whats wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this particular software but limiting JVM heap size to 512Mb **max** may be insufficient.

Try setting initial heap size to 512 Mb and maximum to 2 Gb with `-Xms512m -Xmx2g`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help. For some reason the environment path i created has been remove. I have to create an environment path again. That solve the problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Fo some reason the environment variable of java has been removed. I have to set it again. That solve the problem